# wordpress fishpig magento installation - getPostListHtml()

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, foreach, slug

I have a wordpress installation on my magento store utilizing the 3rd party module fishpig.

I have a page called list.phtml which posts all the content from a category using `$this->getPostListHtml()` I added another div and replicated it but now it's just duplicating the posts from the first div into the second. How do i make a unique second div so when posts are made on the backend it only posts to the second div on the same page. Currently i'm getting category by slug and post collection and then setting order (asc) and then i'm looping through category and riders for each page that is pulling similar content. I have several pages but on each rider page it will still have to have Team 2 posts below Team. I hope that makes sense.

cpt/team/list.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Team (Rider) - Landing Page
 */
/* @var $this test_Wordpress_Block_Cpt_Type_View */

/* @var $helper test_Wordpress_Helper_Data */
$helper = $this->helper('wordpress');
/* @var $postType Fishpig_Wordpress_Addon_CPT_Model_Type */
$postType = $this->getPostType();
$categorySlug = $this->getCurrentCategorySlug();
$allCategories = $helper->getAllCategories();

$instagramHandles = array(
    'skate' => 'testskate',
    'surf' => 'testsurf',
    'snow' => 'testsnow',
    'mx' => 'testmx',
    'testunity' => 'testunity',
    'girls' => 'testgirls',
);

$textRider = ($categorySlug == 'testunity') ? 'Ambassador' : 'Rider';
$htmlRiderPicks = $this->getChildHtml('picks');
$hasEvents = ($events = $this->getChild('events') && $this->getChild('events')->getTotal());
$_theseRiders = array();
?>
<?php if($categorySlug): ?>
    <?php $curCategory = $helper->getCategoryBySlug($categorySlug) ?>
    <?php $riders = $curCategory->getPostCollection()->addPostTypeFilter($postType->getPostType())->setOrder('menu_order','asc'); ?>
    <div class="team-header row">
        <div class="columns">
            <h1 class="team-page-title"><?php echo $this->__('Team'); ?></h1>

            <ul class="team-categories j-team-category-list">
                <?php foreach($helper->getTeamCategories() as $category): /* @var $category Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post_Category */ ?>
                    <li  class="j-team-title <?php if($category->getSlug() == $categorySlug): ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></a>
                        <?php $riders = $category->getPostCollection()->addPostTypeFilter($postType->getPostType())->setOrder('menu_order','asc'); ?>
                            <div class="riders-names-list j-riders-names-list only-mobile-show">
                                <ul>
                                    <?php foreach($riders as $rider): /* @var $rider Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post */ ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $rider->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($rider->getPostTitle()) ?></a>
                                        </li>

                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                    </li>
                    <?php
                        if ($category->getSlug() == $categorySlug) {
                            $_theseRiders = $riders;
                        }
                    ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="riders-names-list mobile-hide">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($_theseRiders as $rider): /* @var $rider Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post */ ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $rider->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($rider->getPostTitle()) ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="team-panel" class="team-panel">
        <div class="riders-panel" id="Rider">
            <div class="riders-list team-riders-list">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $this->getPostListHtml() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <div class="team-header row">

    <div class="columns">
    <h1 class="team-page-title"><?php echo $this->__('Second Team'); ?></h1>

    <div id="second-team-panel" class="second-team-panel">
        <div class="second-riders-panel" id="Second_Rider">
            <div class="riders-list team-riders-list-second">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $this->getPostListHtml() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

---

```
/**
     * Generates and returns the collection of posts
     *
     * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection
     */
    protected function _getPostCollection()
    {
        return Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the HTML for the post collection
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPostListHtml()
    {
        return $this->getPostListBlock()->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the post list block
     *
     * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List
     */
    public function getPostListBlock()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_postListBlock)) {
            if (($block = $this->getChild($this->_postListBlockName)) === false) {
                $block = $this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('wordpress/post_list', $this->_postListBlockName . rand(1111, 9999))
                    ->setTemplate($this->getPostListTemplate());
            }

            $block->setWrapperBlock($this);

            $this->_postListBlock = $block;
        }

        return $this->_postListBlock;
    }
```

cpt/team/renderer/list.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Team (Riders) - List View Renderer
 */
/* @var $this Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List_Renderer */

/* @var $helper test_Wordpress_Helper_Data */
$helper = $this->helper('wordpress');
/* @var $post Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post */
$post = $this->getPost();
$featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage();
/** @var test_Wordpress_Helper_Image $teamHelper */
$imageHelper = $this->helper('test_wordpress/image');
$background = $imageHelper->getBackground($post);
?>
<div class="m-grid-6 columns">
    <div class="rider-list-item fade-item">
        <a class="rider-info" href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>">
             <span class="post-img">
            <img class="rider-background fade-image" src="<?php echo $background; ?>" alt="test Riders" />
            <?php if ($featuredImage): ?>
                <img class="rider-photo " src="<?php echo $featuredImage->getImageByType('thumb-240x220') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
                 </span>
            <span class="rider-list-name"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

cpt/team/renderer/view.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Team (Riders) - Post View Renderer
 *
 */
/* @var $this Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_View */

/* @var $helper test_Wordpress_Helper_Data */
$helper = $this->helper('wordpress');
/* @var $post Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post */
$post = $this->getPost();
$nextPost = $post->getNextPost();
$prevPost = $post->getPreviousPost();
/* @var $postType Fishpig_Wordpress_Addon_CPT_Model_Type */
$postType = $helper->getPostTypeByPost($post);
/* @var $parent Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post_Category */
$parent = $post->getParentCategory();
/** @var test_Wordpress_Helper_Team $teamHelper */
$teamHelper = $this->helper('test_wordpress/team');
$textRider = ($parent->getSlug() == 'testunity') ? 'Ambassador' : 'Rider';
$layoutType = $post->getCustomField('details_layout');

?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="categories-dropdown riders-dropdown">
            <div class="selectBox">
                <select onChange="setLocation(this.value);">
                    <?php foreach($helper->getTeamCategories() as $category): /* @var $category Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post_Category */ ?>
                        <?php $selected = ($category->getId() == $parent->getId()) ? ' selected="true"' : '' ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($postType,$category) ?>"<?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="selectBox">
                <select onChange="setLocation(this.value);">
                    <option value="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($postType,$parent) ?>"><?php echo $helper->__('All '.$textRider.'s') ?></option>
                    <?php $riders = $parent->getPostCollection()->addPostTypeFilter($post->getPostType());?>
                    <?php foreach($riders as $rider): /* @var $rider Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post */ ?>
                        <?php $selected = ($rider->getId() == $post->getId()) ? ' selected="true"' : '' ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $rider->getPermalink() ?>"<?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($rider->getPostTitle()) ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row artists-arrows">
        <div class="columns">
            <?php if ($prevPost instanceof Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post && $prevPost->getId()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $prevPost->getPermaLink(); ?>" class="artist-previous">
                    <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i><?php echo $helper->__('Previous') ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($nextPost instanceof Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post && $nextPost->getId()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $nextPost->getPermaLink(); ?>" class="artist-next">
                    <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i><?php echo $helper->__('Next') ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="rider-main-info-wrapper wide-panel">
    <div class="backgrounds">
        <div class="item item_2">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('test_wordpress/slider')->setPost($post)->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rider-main-info row">
        <div class="team-rider-details column">
            <?php $featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage();?>
            <?php if ($featuredImage): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $featuredImage->getImageByType('thumb-240x220') ?>" class="detail-rider-image detail-thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="team-rider-info">
                <h1 class="dark rider-name"><?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?></h1>
                <p class="rider-details-info">
                    <?php if($post->getCustomField('hometown')): ?>
                        <span><?php echo $helper->__('From:') ?> <?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($post->getCustomField('hometown')) ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($post->getCustomField('birthdate') && $helper->getAgeByBirthdate($post->getCustomField('birthdate'))): ?>
                        <span><?php echo $helper->__('Age:') ?> <?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($helper->getAgeByBirthdate($post->getCustomField('birthdate'))) ?></span>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="more-info-wrapper">
        <div class="more-info-content row">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="rider-arrow-show js-more-content">
                    <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
                    <span class="more-text"><?php echo $helper->__('more info') ?></span>
                    <span class="less-text"><?php echo $helper->__('less info') ?></span>
                    <span class="more-text-mobile"><?php echo $helper->__('more') ?></span>
                    <span class="less-text-mobile"><?php echo $helper->__('less') ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="rider-social-icons">
                    <a href="http://facebook.com/<?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($helper->__($post->getCustomField('facebook_handle'))); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook-large"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($helper->__($post->getCustomField('twitter_handle'))); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-twitter-small"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://instagram.com/<?php echo $helper->escapeHtml($helper->__($post->getCustomField('insta_handle'))); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-instagram-large"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rider-content-wrapper">
            <div class="viewport row">
                <div class="overview">
                    <?php if ($layoutType != 'left'): ?>
                        <div class="more-left m-grid-8 columns personal-info">
                            <?php if ($post->getCustomField('birthdate') && $helper->getAgeByBirthdate($post->getCustomField('birthdate'))): ?>
                                <div>
                                    <label><?php echo $helper->__('Birth Date:') ?></label>
                                    <?php echo $helper->formatDate($post->getCustomField('birthdate'),'m/d/y'); ?><br/>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo $post->getPostContent() ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($layoutType != 'right'): ?>
                        <div class="more-right m-grid-4 columns">
                            <?php echo $post->getCustomField('extrastats'); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php $instagramContent = $teamHelper->getInstagramBlock($post); ?>
<?php if($instagramContent): ?>
    <div class="rider-thumb row">
            <?php echo $instagramContent; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('test_wordpress/products')->setPost($post)->setTitle($helper->__('%s Wears',$post->getPostTitle()))->toHtml(); ?>

<?php
$isShowNews = false;
$blockNews = $this->getChild('news.related');
if ($blockNews) {
    $blockNews->setTag($post->getPostTitle());
    $blockNews->setCategory($parent->getSlug());
    if ($blockNews->getPostCollection()->count()) {
        echo $blockNews->toHtml();
        $isShowNews = true;
    }
}
if (!$isShowNews) {
    $blockNews = $this->getChild('news.resent');
    if ($blockNews) {
        $blockNews->setCategory($parent->getSlug());
        echo $blockNews->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: the `$this->getPostListHtml()` is related to the category so how would you want to have other results if you call the same method ? Not sure to understand what result you want. Also $this refers to an instance of an object so we need a bit more code as we don't see how it is instantiate. Maybe you can pass a category.

Comment: I want different results and I understand that i'll have to use a different method. I would like to pass a different category, yes. @Sylwit I'll post more code for that object and how it's instantiated. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Still not enough, please paste all of your both files

Comment: Updated with all the files in that folder directory. @Sylwit

Answer (score 2):

Based on your partially posted code, I can give you only a conceptual answer.

From what you've posted by now your only difference between new and old posts could be synthesised in two ways:

1. By **post_date**, and you can call almost the same function, but with the last displayed post's post_date as parameter so you can filter the new results that has newer post_date. Adding a new closure before or after `setOrder(...)` or by changing the wpQuery;
2. Or by **offset**. Considering that you won't have backdated posts, all new posts will have the offset equal with the initial posts count. so you'll have to `setOffset($oldCount);` This way you'll get latest posts starting from the last displayed post.

You'll just have to update the wp query with the desired parameter, or find a way to tag your posts in some other way:

3. Eaiser way would be to keep track of your displayed post IDs in an array `$displayed_post_ids`, and than query with `post__not_in`, like the following example:

`$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        //... other args
        'post__not_in' => array($displayed_post_ids) // Don't show this posts
    );`

4. Another alternative might be the **post_meta** fields. You'll have more control this way and you can use same old categories for new posts also.
   You can add a post_meta information that won't be displayed in page and that will keep track if your posts have been displayed in the first div or not. Considering is more easy to alter the posts that you already have, you can add a post_meta `_wasDisplayed` (using something like `update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wasDisplayed', true);` when you display the post in the first div can also do the trick )

You can set a default **false** value of that post_meta value for all your posts on creation. This will help you on the query.
On the second div you will call the generator function and check if your posts have the post_meta and if it's **false**.

Also you can reset the post_meta values later if you need.

For implementation is also needed to be know how many posts you intend to display, if you use pagination and other small details that could make your work a bit more complex.

**Notice - this case solution:**

**5.  As you're business logic seem to be related more to categories, there's a more straightforward solution:** 
On the backed process that adds new posts assign an additional category to every new post (something called like: "New Undisplayed Posts") this category will be used as a filter argument in the second div.
Take into account that you'll have to remove this category from all the posts that are posted at the time you call the `getPostListHtml()` from the first div, otherwise you will have unwanted posts in the second div.

You can make this happen in a wrapper function using one of the category arguments for wp query object:

```
Category Parameters
```

Show posts associated with certain categories.

```
cat (int) - use category id.
category_name (string) - use category slug.
category__and (array) - use category id.
category__in (array) - use category id.
category__not_in (array) - use category id.
```

Hope it helps,
Codrut, KMM

Comment: Hi Codrut, so there is no way that i can simply use the $this->getPostListHtml() but attach a new category id to this post object? Perhaps to force it to display all posts from a particular category? @KRONMARK MEDIA

Comment: Off course there is. The solution is very tight related to your app logic.
I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Just checking in with you on the final answer? I cannot use this because it will just duplicate the posts.                  <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $this->getPostListHtml() ?>
                </div>

Comment: Have you worked out the entire logic?
I mean:
1. Add the "NEW" category to DB and retrieve the assigned ID - for filtering reference.
2. Display categories in DIV1 and also remove the so called "NEW" category from the displayed posts.
3. Set DIV2 to display only posts that are in the "NEW" category.
4. Set the "NEW" category on newly created posts so that the DIV2 contains them -
And surely make sure you have some mechanism to ensure refreshing only the DIV2 data once there are new posts on backend.
For step 4 you have to make a change to the filtering and include the category "NEW"!